# How do I install/use the backbone.js framework?

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, web

I'm new to JavaScript and was wondering how you install the backbone framework so that you can use it with javascript.

Comment: If you're that new to javascript what are your reasons for wanting to use backbone.js?

Comment: Download the underscore.js and backbone.js files at their respective sites, include them in your html file in the same order, and after them place your own script (where you'll already be able to work with backbone).

Comment: But Lee Taylor makes a good point.

Comment: Being new to javascript wouldn't be a big deal if the user had a strong grasp of programming in general. But based on the question, it sounds like new to programming... in which I agree that diving into Backbone might not be the best idea.

Comment: I've got a solid grasp of OOP concepts and languages but am pretty new to web development.

Comment: get your hands dirty first with plain JavaScript before you dive in to libraries such as backbone.js

Comment: Then jump into jQuery and get familiar selecting, traversing, and manipulating the DOM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JOPLOmacedo’s first comment contains the essential answer, but I’ll elaborate it a bit:

Download jquery.js from the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) site, underscore.js from the [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) site, and 
`Backbone.js` from the [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) site. Use the “development versions” first, as this may help you in debugging. You can place the `.js` files in the same folder as your own test files, to keep things simple. (Later, you will find it better to place them in a separate folder.

In your HTML code, write (e.g. after all content, right before the end tag `<body>` if you use one:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="underscore.js"></script>
<script src="backbone.js"></script>
<script>
// Your own JavaScript code here
</script>
```

This should get you started. You can use e.g. the relatively simple Hello world code in the [Hello Backbone.js tutorial](http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/) to check that the installation is OK, before working on your own code. (The tutorial uses remotely hosted versions of the .js file, which is another possibility.)